# PyQT with QT Creator

Tags: python, qt-creator, pyside2

I am trying to develop a small gui using PySide and the QT Creator.
As the base implementation, I have choosen a `QMainWindow`.
The problem is that adding any elements to that MainWindow inside the Editor results in an empty window when I run the code.

The initially generated python code looks like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know that `loader.load(ui_file, self)` returns a widget. My solution was:

```
 def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file, self)
        self.window.show()
        ui_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MainWindow()
    #widget.show()     <<<<<<--- removing this 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works for me but this clearly cannot be the way this is supposed to work.
I am confused on why QT Creator gives me this non-working templaet.

---

Furthermore I am curious on how custom functions should be implemented.
When clicking on the `clicked()` slot for a button, it tells me

```
No ui_form.h found! (translated)
```

I ended up writing the functions into my `MainWindow` class like this:

```
self.window.menuopen_button.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.menu_animation(x))
self.window.minimise_button.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.menu_buttons('minimise'))
```

Comment: I don't know why PySide doesn't provide a loadUi function (but, since they don't have any, they only provide the QUiLoader solution, which to me is insufficient as it inhibits subclassing). Since you're using PyQt5, though, I suggest you to use the `uic` module, which provides loadUi() which "installs" the ui on the *current* widget. Just add `uic.loadUi('path', self)` at the beginning of the `__init__`. This obviously assumes you're using a ui for a main window, otherwise you can just use `setCentralWidget()` with the widget returned by QUiLoader().

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to tell you. I am using PySide2

Comment: So ho wwould uic.loadUi('path',self) work with PySide2 or do you recommend I use PyQt5?

Comment: Then please use the correct tags and names: PyQt and PySide are both python bindings to Qt, but while their behavior and usage is almost always the same, they differ in some parts (and cannot be used together). Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience with PySide, so I cannot tell you how to work around that. For what I know, PySide simply doesn't provide that, and there's no direct way to solve that, unless somebody just decide to create a module that mimics PyQt's loadUi; so, the only solution left is to always use pyuic generated files and use the multiple inheritance.

Comment: So I switched to PyQt5 in the meantime since I was only working with a single file so far.
I thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code only loads the UI file into the QUiLoader object - you don't do anything else with it. When you call `widget.show()`, you're calling the QMainWindow's show method which is a default window (and, hence, empty) since you haven't added the loaded widget to it.

Your solution similarly loads the UI but displays it via the widget object's show method. However, you're not amending it to your main window, so you're basically tossing your main window and just using the widget.

There are a couple ways to correctly accomplish what you want:

1. One way would be to, as @musicamante suggested, add the loaded UI widget to your MainWindow object (and by the way, this *is* supported by PySide2: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html - the example in the detailed description shows exactly how to do this).
2. Or the other way, which I prefer, would be to use the uic utility, PySide2-uic, in the build process to generate a UI Python class based on the UI file.

The Qt documentation has [tutorials showing both methods](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html). The linked documentation shows PySide6 as support for PySide2 has been discontinued with the release of Qt6. The API for PySide2, PySide6, and PyQt5 are all very similar, so if you're migrating from either PySide2 or PyQt then the change should be relatively painless. I recommend using PySide6 as this is the Python binding officially supported by Qt.